# Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com

Tags: api, symfony, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe in my `symfony` 3.4 project , but I am getting this error :

```
Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com.

(Network error [errno 92]: HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1))
```

This the stripe part of code in my controller action :

```
    public function viewPostAction(){
      \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_JKYj1WMuOsnaD5nOXiAYaPXr
");

\Stripe\Charge::create([
  "amount" => 2000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "source" => "tok_visa", // obtained with Stripe.js
  "description" => "Charge for jenny.rosen@example.com"
]);

    $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->findAll();
        return $this->render("pages/index.html.twig",['post' => $post]);
    }
```

This is the stripe html form  :

```
  <form  method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

Can someone please help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Does your sever support making outbound TLS 1.2 requests? https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-stripe-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2

Comment: @karllekko i solved it the problem was from the TLS 1.2 requests like you said